# Javascript compare two object keys making new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two objects. If a key appears in both objects, I want the first object's value as a key and second object's value as a value.

```
var obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"}
var obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};
```

the output should look like this:

```
{"value1":"index1","value2":"index2","value3":"index3"}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the entries ([key, value]) from the 1st object, and use reduce to combine with the values from the 2nd object if the key exists in `obj2` as well:

```js
const obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"};
const obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};

const result = Object.entries(obj1) // get the entries
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    if(k in obj2) { // if the key exists in obj2
      r[v] = obj2[k]; // use the value from obj1 as the key, with the value from obj2
    }
  
    return r
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

With lodash, you can get the keys from both objects, and use `_.intersection()` to find the common keys. Then you can get the values from each object with `_.at()`, and combine both arrays of values to an object with `_.zipObject()`:

```js
const obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"};
const obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};

// get the keys that exists in both objects
const keys = _.intersection(_.keys(obj1), _.keys(obj2));
const result = _.zipObject( // combine arrays of values to an object
  _.at(obj1, keys), // get the values from obj1
  _.at(obj2, keys), // get the values from obj2
)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through **obj1**'s keys and use **obj1**'s value as key and **obj2**'s value as value.

```js
const obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"}
const obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};

const newObj = {};

for (let key in obj1)
    if (obj2[key])
     newObj[obj1[key]] = obj2[key];

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: But you didn't compare if the keys match or not, you assume they are identical, what if they are not

Comment: @OnerT. Edited the content to check the key match

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"}
var obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};

var obj = {};

for( let i in obj1) {
  if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(i))
    obj[ obj1[i] ] = obj2[i];
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You can use `if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(i))` or `if(i in obj2)` instead of creating an array of keys and check `includes` for every `i`

Comment: Sure! That's much straight forward. Will edit it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj1 = {a:"value1",b:"value2",c:"value3"}
var obj2 = {a:"index1",b:"index2",c:"index3",d:"index4"};

/* iterate on all the props of obj1*/
const result=Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc,obj1Prop)=>{
/*if obj2[value of propObj1] is not undefined */
if(typeof obj2[obj1Prop] !== "undefined"){
// assign the value of obj2[value of propObj1] to accumulator
 acc[obj1[obj1Prop]]=obj2[obj1Prop];
  }
  return acc;

},{})
//result contains the result
console.log(result)
```